# How to create smiling/crying animation?

Tags: animation, workflow

I need to create a few models for my new game. A cube with a smiling face that gradually changes to a sad face and a cube with melting animation i.e melts completely within 10 seconds.

Is this possible with blender. If yes, then how?

Comment: this type of question is better suited to http://blenderartists.org/

Comment: Why can't we just answer this with shape keys? sounds reasonable to me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this with shape keys. First make the cube that had the smiling face. Then go to *Properties > object data > shape keys* and add a basis key. Now add another shape key.Go to the mesh and make the face to the frowning guy.  you can pan between the two keys slowly to make it form into the other.

[image]

The higher you set the value, the more frowny your guy will appear.